# How to avoid RewriteRule for specific directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This is my current `.htaccess` data.

```
# permalinks
RewriteEngine on

# users
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]{2,15})$ /user.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Which obviously means that

```
http://testsite.net/asantos
```

is parsed as:

```
http://testsite.net/user.php?username=asantos
```

The website also has an **inc** directory in the root, and if I open this url

```
http://testsite.net/inc/
```

it actually redirects to:

```
http://testsite.net/inc/?username=inc
```

How can I avoid that behavior for existing directories that are in the root of the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I avoid that behavior for existing directories that are in the root of the website?

Use:

```
# permalinks
RewriteEngine on

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules *below*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]{2,15})$ /user.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]

# more rules here
```

Comment: Do I have to specify those `RewriteCond` conditions before each `RewriteRule`?

Comment: see my updated answer, now you don't need to repeat these conditions for all the rules below this skip rule.

Comment: One more case, it's not working if I use testsite.net/inc - it only works if I use testsite.net/inc/

Comment: It should work for `/inc` as well. I've tested this and and it works for a directory with or without slash. Make sure you don't have `DIrectorySlash Off` anywhere. (or else add `DIrectorySlash on` at top of this .htaccess)